# Can't figure out this JSON parsing error

Tags: android, json

Currently I'm trying to display JSON data (hosted on a Webserver) in a `ListView` in Android. The App correctly receives the data but is unable to process it further to display it in said `ListView`.

The error is as follows:
`JSON parsing error: Value ... of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`

The JSON data I'm trying to parse looks like the following:
`[{"idBuch":1,"autor":"Erich Maria Remarque","name":"Im Westen nichts Neues","preis":20,"buchtyp":{"idBuchtyp":3,"typenamen":"Geschichte"}}]`

The code that processes the received JSON-String:

```
try{
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
  JSONArray books = jsonObject.getJSONArray("book");

  for(int i = 0; i < books.length(); i++){
     JSONObject obj = books.getJSONObject(i);

     String idBook = obj.getString("idBuch");
     String author = obj.getString("autor");
     String name = obj.getString("name");
     String price = obj.getString("preis");

     JSONObject booktype = obj.getJSONObject("buchtyp");
     String idBooktype = booktype.getString("idBuchtyp");
     String typename = booktype.getString("typenamen");

     HashMap<String, String> book = new HashMap<>();

     book.put("idBook", idBook);
     book.put("author", author);
     book.put("name", name);
     book.put("price", price);
     book.put("genre", typename);

     bookList.add(book);
 } }catch(final JSONException e)
```

I am aware of the fact that there are a lot of similar questions on this site but I still had no success regarding this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code does not work with your test string; the code is looking for `{"book":[...]}`

Comment: If your JSON is as written, then you should start by doing `JSONArray books = new JSONArray(jsonStr)` and not your first two lines.

Comment: My bad...but removing it or using `jsonStr` again makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON that you provided only contains an array.

```
[
  {
    "idBuch": 1,
    "autor": "Erich Maria Remarque",
    "name": "Im Westen nichts Neues",
    "preis": 20,
    "buchtyp": {
      "idBuchtyp": 3,
      "typenamen": "Geschichte"
    }
  }
]
```

However, your code expects the root to be an object with field book.

```
{
  "book": [
    {
      "idBuch": 1,
      "autor": "Erich Maria Remarque",
      "name": "Im Westen nichts Neues",
      "preis": 20,
      "buchtyp": {
        "idBuchtyp": 3,
        "typenamen": "Geschichte"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case, try replacing the line:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

with

```
JSONArray books = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

and proceed as normal. Your end result should look like:

```
try {
 JSONArray books = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

 for (int i = 0; i < books.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject obj = books.getJSONObject(i);

  String idBook = obj.getString("idBuch");
  String author = obj.getString("autor");
  String name = obj.getString("name");
  String price = obj.getString("preis");

  JSONObject booktype = obj.getJSONObject("buchtyp");
  String idBooktype = booktype.getString("idBuchtyp");
  String typename = booktype.getString("typenamen");

  HashMap < String, String > book = new HashMap < > ();

  book.put("idBook", idBook);
  book.put("author", author);
  book.put("name", name);
  book.put("price", price);
  book.put("genre", typename);

  bookList.add(book);
 }
} catch (final JSONException e) {
 e.printStackTrace()
}
```